# How to migrate existing Angular 2 TypeScript app to ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, migrate

We have an existing codebase which is written in Angular 2 using TypeScript. But now we are planning to migrate the codebase to ReactJS. I am not very sure how can we do this, without rewriting the entire codebase separately from the existing code.

What I am looking for a solution that can allow us to use both Angular and React Components and their dependencies working in correlation with each other.

Answer (score -1):

This is a painfull process but is actually doable. The resulting app will be eventualy unmainteneable so I suggest you to do this only for the transition to the React app refactored.

Some examples:

**Example: Integrating angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker**

```js
angular
  .module('ngApp', ['ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker'])

class AngularWidget extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    angular.bootstrap(this.container, ['ngApp']);
  }
  
  html = `<datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.date"></datetimepicker>`;

  render = () => (
    <div
      ref={c => this.container = c}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.html}}
      />
  );
}
```

**Example: Hacking UI Router**

```js
componentDidMount() {
  angular.module('ngApp')
    .run(($state) => {
      $state.go = (state, params, options) => {
        console.log('hijacked ui router');
      }
    })
  angular.bootstrap(this.container, ['ngApp']);
}
```

**Example: Neutralize Angular’s location tampering**

```js
angular.module('ngApp', [])
    .config( ['$provide', function ($provide){
        $provide.decorator('$browser', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
            $delegate.onUrlChange = function () {};
            $delegate.url = function () { return ""};
            return $delegate;
        }]);
    }]);
```

**Example: Clean up angular app when component unmounts**

```js
class AngularWidget extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.$rootScope = angular.injector(['ng', 'ngApp']).get('$rootScope');
    angular.bootstrap(this.container, ['ngApp']);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.$rootScope.$destroy();
  }
  render = () => (
    <div
      ref={c => { this.container = c; }}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: '<widget></widget>' }}
    />
  )
}
```

Ref: https://medium.com/appifycanada/angular-components-in-react-2c929130f995

Comment: This seems to be for AngularJS, I was looking out for something for Angular 2 TypeScript components.

Comment: That's actually similar as way of port, you have only to configure webpack for typescript but basically the approach remain the same

Comment: Okay, I will try.

Comment: question was about Angular 2 not AngularJS